# Find a nodes 8 neighbors on a 2D grid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 2d, nearest-neighbor

I need to find the cardinal and diagonal neighbors of any node in a two dimensional array. Take the below array. I'm searching from the 1 which is [1, 1] on the array. It should return the surrounding 0's. I can find the neighbors just find as shown in some of the below code but they're too slow.

```
[[0, 0, 0]
 [0, 1, 0]
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

I can brute force it like this to return the coordinates of all 8 surrounding nodes.

```
def ReturnNeighbors(x, y):
    numpy.array([(x-1, y), (x, y-1), (x+1, y), (x, y+1),
               (x-1, y-1), (x+1, y+1), (x-1, y+1), (x+1, y-1)])

def ReturnNeighbors_4(x, y):
    for i in xrange(x - 1, x + 2):
        for j in xrange(y - 1, y + 2):
            if (i, j) != (x, y):
                yield (i, j)
```

Or by calculating the distance to all nodes and returning those with a distance < 2 but these and the other solutions I've figured out are slow. The whole reason I'm learning to numpy is for the speed. I think I need to use scipy convolve2d or a cKDtree but they're too complicated for me.

The way I handled this before switching to numpy is my array was full of actual node objects as the values. Each object stored its x and y coordinates in the grid and a set of its neighbors. Like this. I can't use this method anymore as filling a gigantic array full of nodes takes ages. Even in a small 100x100 map that's 10000 node objects! I plan to later not only have much larger maps but multiple maps active at any given time. I've actually ran out of memory trying to create bigger maps due to the nodes imprint. It works for little dungeons but not worlds with multiple maps being simulated.

```
ExampleNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.neighbors = set()

        # The neighbors are found and added to the above set later.

node = Example(0, 0)

for neighbor in node.neighbors:
    do thing with each neighbor
```

I need a nodes neighbors for a variety of reasons. Smoothing a map using cellular automata, splattering blood nearby in combat, pathfinding with breadth first search and more. This is for a roguelike I'm creating. The brute force method works fine for small 60x60 dungeons but now I'm expanding the scope and generating a world map. It's only 200x200 and irritatingly slow.

Comment: Are those always 0's or 1's only in the array? Do you need the indices of those 8 neighbors or just the elements themselves?

Comment: The array is full of a ton of different integers. The 0's are land, the 1's water, the 2's trees and so fourth. I need the coordinates of each of the 8 neighbors.

Comment: How do we handle the boundary conditions, i.e. for 1s at the boundaries for which it won't have 8 neighbors. What about when two 1s share neighbors, should we still report the overlapping neighbors twice for each pivoting 1?

Comment: If their aren't 8 neighbors then it should just return how ever many neighbors are available. Like at the very edge of the array it should return 5 neighbors or in a corner it should return 3 because the other neighbors don't exist beyond the boundary. The second question is kind of beyond my understanding. I'm not sure what you mean by overlapping and pivoting.

Comment: I am assuming you are running `ReturnNeighbors` func across all X's and Y's of all positions of 1 in the input array.
So going with that assumption, now let's say you bunch of `1s` in input array and you want eight neighbors for each 1 in it. And then, if you have few 1s close enough, their neighbors might be the same, so should we still report them regardless? Also if the asumption is true, I would advise posting a generic sample case with 1s at the boundary and close enough bunch of 1s and also post the expected output in the format you would like it to be.

Comment: It doesn't matter if neighbors are shared so yes they should still be reported.

Comment: Let me elaborate on the last part of my last comment again - It would be really nice if you could consider bunch of 1s and *not just one 1* in the input array and post (edit the question just you like did few mins ago) the expected output(assuming you want the neighbors of all 1s). Why am I asking this? Because since you mentioned that for the boundary 1s, we won't have 8 neighbors, so it won't have the "nice" datatype  with NumPy arrays, unless you are okay with object datatypes.

Comment: I updated my main post with a work in progress example from my project. It doesn't work correctly but It's as close as I've gotten so far with my blind experimentation. I'm just trying to find a faster version of the first ReturnNeighbors function I posted, basically. If considering bunches would help then I'm all for it. I think the confusion between us is that you think I'm searching only nodes of a certain value like the 1. I'm normally looping through the entire grid and finding each neighbors nodes one at a time but sometimes I also just need to find the neighbors of just one node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the input array is named `A` that holds all the integers and we are working on just the elements that are `1s` in it and would try to get their neighbours. Here's one approach to do so -

```
# Get offsets for row and column
R_offset,C_offset = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-1,2),np.arange(-1,2))

# Get row and column indices for places where elements are 1s
R_match,C_match = np.nonzero(A==1)

# Store number of matches as it would be frequently used
N = R_match.size

# Get offsetted row, col indices for all matches
R_idx = (R_match[:,None,None] + R_offset).reshape(N,-1)
C_idx = (C_match[:,None,None] + C_offset).reshape(N,-1)

# Based on boundary conditions set invalid ones to zeros
valid_mask = (R_idx>=0) & (C_idx>=0) & (R_idx<A.shape[0]) & (C_idx<A.shape[1])
valid_mask[:,4] = 0 # Set the pivot(self/center) ones to invalid

# Using valid mask, "cut off" elements from each group of 9 elems
cut_idx = valid_mask.sum(1).cumsum()

# Finally form groups
grps_R = np.split(R_idx[valid_mask],cut_idx)[:-1]
grps_C = np.split(C_idx[valid_mask],cut_idx)[:-1]
```

Sample run and explanation on how to interpret and use the outputs -

```
In [256]: A
Out[256]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

In [257]: grps_R
Out[257]: [array([1, 0, 1]), array([1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3, 2])]

In [258]: grps_C
Out[258]: [array([0, 1, 1]), array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]), array([3, 3, 4])]
```

Thus, we have three groups based on the three `1s` in `A`.

The first one is at the top left corner -

```
In [259]: np.column_stack((R_match[0],C_match[0]))  # First point
Out[259]: array([[0, 0]])

In [260]: np.column_stack((grps_R[0],grps_C[0]))    # Its three neighbors
Out[260]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```

The second one is at `(2,2)` -

```
In [263]: np.column_stack((R_match[1],C_match[1]))  # Second point 
Out[263]: array([[2, 2]])

In [264]: np.column_stack((grps_R[1],grps_C[1]))    # Its eight neighbors
Out[264]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 3]])
```

Finally the third one is at `(4,5)` -

```
In [265]: np.column_stack((R_match[2],C_match[2]))  # Third point 
Out[265]: array([[3, 4]])

In [266]: np.column_stack((grps_R[2],grps_C[2]))    # Its three neighbors
Out[266]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [3, 3],
       [2, 4]])
```

Comment: This is great. It resulted in a huge speed improvement for my cellular automata related stuff! I don't think it solves my problem though unless I don't understand how to use it. This returns all the neighbors of all values of a specific type if I understand correctly. In other words, it gives me the neighbors of all the 1's. I just need the neighbors of one very specific node though. I want to pass a [x, y] coordinate to a function and return that coordinates neighbors. The answer was never the less helpful with improving other parts of my code so thank you.

Comment: @Patwollip I guess in that one node case, you can edit `R_match,C_match = np.nonzero(A==1)` to `R_match,C_match = x,y`. Give it a try?

Comment: It complains about `N = R_match.size` after making the change stating AttributeError "int" object has no attribute "size." I guess that makes sense since a nodes x, y coordinates aren't numpy related anymore.

Comment: @Patwollip Yeah for that you can use `N = len(R_match)` I think.